# how to add multiple arrays in form in mysql database php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a form that is fetching database entries of a product. I have added multiple rows of the products in a form, and I need help in database insertion.
I want data to be added in a single row and I have multiple arrays.

```
<form id='students' method='post' name='students' action='add-      
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()"/></th>
                <th>S. No</th>
                <th>BarCode</th>
                <th>HSN</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>MRP</th>
                 <th>CGST</th>
                 <th>SGST</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td>
                <td><span name='snum[]' id='snum'>1.</span></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='countryname_1' name='countryname[]'/></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='country_no_1' name='country_no[]'/></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='phone_code_1' name='phone_code[]'/></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='country_code_1' name='country_code[]'/> </td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='cgst_1' name='cgst1[]'/> </td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='sgst_1' name='sgst1[]'/> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        <button type="button" class='btn btn-danger delete'>- Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class='btn btn-success addmore'>+ Add More</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please put some effort

Comment: What is your table structure and desired output? Do you want a row per product index? All of them comma separated? etc. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your form is wrong--- `<form id='students' method='post' name='students' action='add- ` **<--** close it here

Comment: @kchason- yes i need  row per product  index,
i tried pair() and basic method to store array, but i am limited to add array of same name, but here i have 5 different name arrays that is causing a problem for me.

Comment: @B001 - thanks but i placed form only for a fair idea of arrays

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to store arrays in database. It is not possible per se, but you can use the serialize() function and unserialize() when you fetch data.

[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Comment: thanks michal- can you please assist in details, sounds like it will solve the problem